# Getting the server side call?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, webclient

Now, I've spent less than a year working as a developer and thus far one small, and likely really simple, gap in my knowledge is how to see the calls which are made to managed code from javascript.

I've been able to get around this by mainly hitting CTRL+F in Visual Studio and just finding all instances of a C# method call referenced in javascript. Googling for an alternative way of getting these calls hasn't yielded anything so I thought this would be the best place to ask.

Let me give you an example; in my javascript I have a method called `buildStats(data)` which takes in (spoiler alert) some data. I would like to see what that data contains in my managed C# code before it reaches the javascript. How can I find out the C# method that passes data to that javascript method? (Similar to how hitting `SHIFT + F12` on a C# method brings up all times a particular method is referenced).

Comment: The call is either made server-side and baked into the page or made over HTTP, typically using a REST API (or if you're still rocking hammer pants, a SOAP API).

Comment: @Novastorm Are you referring to ASP.Net?

Comment: Hit F12 in your browser and use the developer console to see the contents of all the HTTP requests between the browser and server.

Comment: @ssube I've not heard of those terms before, we're using Ajax and Webmethods for our code

Comment: @Wimmel I am indeed; apologises I should have made that more clear in the question & tags. I've just edited the tags :)

Comment: @Novastorm you should really google how AJAX works then.  You pass information via AJAX and it is, generally, handled on the server via a controller -- which generates something callled a 'view' which is then passed back to the client side JS via a response.  Google: 'AJAX', 'REST', 'Model View Controller'.  This stuff is NEED TO KNOW.  It sounds like you have no idea how the place you're working at accomplishes it's workflow.  Ask your team for help.

Comment: @hownowbrowncow At which point was my question referring to Ajax? I was asking if there was an easier way to search for the calls that are made to the controller, not how to pass data around

Comment: AJAX (and some other techniques like Web Sockets) are the only way that JavaScript can invoke server side code, besides plain HTTP requests.